# ExtJS 5.0.1: Unable to use anonymous models in a Session

Tags: session, extjs, mvvm, data-binding, extjs5

I'm getting this error:

> [E] Ext.data.Session.checkModelType(): Unable to use anonymous models
>   in a Session

when trying to use a Session when binding a Grid with a Store via ViewModel:

**ViewModel:**

```
Ext.define('App.view.gridViewModel', { 
        extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel', 
        alias: 'viewmodel.gridview', 

         stores:{ 
                 gridstore: { 
                         model: 'gridView', 
                         autoLoad: true, 
                         //This triggers the Exception: 
                         session: true, 
                         listeners: { 
                                beforeload: function(store, operation, eOpts) { 
                                        var oProxy = this.getProxy(); 
                                        oProxy.setExtraParams({ 
                                                tableName: 'dbo.SomeTable' 
                                                , identityKey: "id" 
                                                , primaryKey: ["id"] 
                                                , mode: "readonly" 
                                                , lang: "es" 
                                                , output: 'json' 
                                        }); 
                                } 
                         } 
                 } 
         } 
});
```

**View:**

```
Ext.define('App.view.gridView', { 
        extend: 'Ext.form.Panel', 

        //... 

        viewModel: { 
                type: 'gridview' 
        }, 

        controller: 'gridview', 

        // Create a session for this view 
        session:true, 

        items: [{ 
                xtype: 'grid', 
                reference: 'myGrid', 
                bind: '{gridstore}', 
                columns: [ 
                        //... 
                ] 
        }] 

        //... 
});
```

Model's data is fetch through a Proxy:

**Model:**

Ext.define("App.model.gridView", { 
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

```
schema: { 
    namespace: 'App.model' 
}, 

proxy: { 
    //proxy remote api stuff...... 
}. 

idProperty: 'id'. 
primaryKeys: 'id'. 
fields: [ 
    //fields 
]
```

});

I have no idea what an **anonymous model** is and I haven't found anything related in the web, **any ideas?**

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 0):

The reason seems to be that in my Server's response I have a JSON Object called "metaData", which collides with the one available in JSON Reader:

> Response MetaData
>
> The server can return metadata in its response, in addition to the
>   record data, that describe attributes of the data set itself or are
>   used to reconfigure the Reader. To pass metadata in the response you
>   simply add a metaData attribute to the root of the response data. The
>   metaData attribute can contain anything, but supports a specific set
>   of properties that are handled by the Reader if they are present:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json

The curious thing is that I don't use any of the available metaData options for JSON Reader, nothing related to any **anonymous model**, therefore **this might  be considered a bug**